# Taylor expansion of $f(z) = z^2/(z+1)^2$ around $i$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, complex-numbers, taylor-expansion

***Question:***

Let $f$ be the function :

$$f(z) = \bigg(\frac{z}{z+1}\bigg)^2 = \bigg(1-\frac{1}{1+z}\bigg)^2 = 1 -2\frac{1}{1+z} + \frac{1}{(1+z)^2}$$

Find the *Taylor* expansion of the function $f$ around $i$ and also the convergence radius.

***Attempt:***

From the *Cauchy-Taylor* theorem :

$$f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n(z-i)^n = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{f^{(n)}(i)}{n!}(z-i)^n,|z-i|<R $$

We have to calculate the $a_n = \frac{f^{(n)}(i)}{n!}, \forall n\in \mathbb N$ and the radius of convergence $R$.

Now, in similar exercises, all fraction function could be manipulated to give you such a form around the expansion point, that could be used to be set as $w$, in order to use one of the known geometric series :

$$\frac{1}{1-w} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}w^n ,|w|<1$$
$$\frac{1}{1+w} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^nw^n,|w|<1$$

And after having such an expression, by differentiating the geometric series, you'd be getting the final expression of the  *Taylor Expansion*, since the function has one and only series expansion. Finally, to get the convergence radiues, you would just solve the expression $|w|<1$, where $w$ would be a fraction-function of $z-i$.

My problem with the particular example is that I cannot seem to find a way (or my head is stuck) to make such an expression, thus I cannot continue with the steps I've mentioned.

I'd appreciate a thorough help/solution or any advice and tips on such problems, because it's a new subject I'm working on, on our Complex Analysis Semester.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Hint: $$\frac1{1+z}=\frac1{1+i+z-i}=\frac1{1+i}\frac1{1+\frac{z-i}{1+i}}$$

Comment: One approach would be via
$\dfrac{1}{(1+z)^2}=\dfrac{1}{((1+i)+(z-i))^2}=\dfrac{1}{(1+i)^2}\dfrac{1}{(1-\frac{z-i}{-1-i})^2}=$ $=c\dfrac{1}{(1-u)^2}=c\dfrac{d}{du}\dfrac{1}{1-u}=c\dfrac{d}{du}\sum_{n=0}^\infty u^n$ where you end up with a double sum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good strategy is to set $z=w+i$ and find the Taylor expansion at $0$. The function becomes
$$
g(w)=f(w+i)=\frac{(w+i)^2}{(w+i+1)^2}
$$
and it is clear you need the Taylor expansion of
$$
\frac{1}{(w+i+1)^2}=
\frac{1}{(1+i)^2}\frac{1}{\bigl(1+\frac{w}{1+i}\bigr)^2}
$$
Set $v=-w/(1+i)$: you now need the expansion of
$$
\frac{1}{(1-v)^2}
$$
which is known: integrate and differentiate. Then substitute, multiply by $w^2+2iw-1$ and change back $w=z-i$.

Answer (score 1):

Derivatives of $f(z)$ are not so hard to find, after all:
$$
f^{(n)}(z)=2(-1)^{n+1}{n!\over(1+z)^{n+1}}+(-1)^{n+2}{(n+1)!\over(1+z)^{n+2}}
,\quad n\ge1.
$$
Substituting here $z=i$ and taking into account that $1+i=\sqrt2e^{i\pi/4}$, we can find:
$$
a_n={f^{(n)}(i)\over n!}=\left({e^{3i\pi/4}\over\sqrt2}\right)^{n+1}
\left(2+(n+1){e^{3i\pi/4}\over\sqrt2}\right),
\quad n\ge1,
$$
and of course $a_0=f(i)={i\over2}$.

The radius of convergence can be found from 
$R=\lim\limits_{n\to+\infty}\left|{a_n\over a_{n+1}}\right|=\sqrt2$,
which is obvious, as $f(z)$ has a pole at $z=-1$.